# battery is showing 0% with an exclaimation mark in Toshiba Satellite C850

Tags: power-management, 20.04, battery, toshiba-satellite, toshiba

[image: Here is the output of dmesg | grep -i acpi Part 4][image: Here is the output of dmesg | grep -i acpi Part 3][image: Here is the output of dmesg | grep -i acpi Part 2][image: Here is the output of dmesg | grep -i acpi Part 1][image: This is the information regarding my make and model of laptop]I am new to Ubuntu, I have installed it recently, but my battery is showing 0% with an exclaimation mark although my laptop is fully charged. Please help me out. 
[image: Here is the picture of my power settings]

Comment: Send details about your laptop.  Make and Model.  Could be that Power settings like that are not coming back from your battery.  Could be a broken sensor in the battery.

Comment: but i have windows installed in it as well. And its power status is completely fine

Comment: Hello @Adeena.  Good troubleshooting. That does mean the battery and circuitry is fine. It is most likely that it just doesn't "talk" to Ubuntu well.  It may come in time. If you want help you will need to add your Make and Model of computer.

Comment: I have edited the question. Kindly see the details of my laptop.

Comment: Well done. That is clear.  If you edit your title to add Toshiba Satellite C850 you may get more hits.

Comment: Ok lets hope so

Comment: This isn't exactly the same, but maybe it will work for you? http://sirlagz.net/2016/12/09/ubuntu-missing-battery-on-toshiba-satellite-laptop/

Comment: I followed the procedure but nothing happened

Comment: @AdeenaLathiya Can you also post output of `dmesg | grep -i acpi` ?

Comment: I have edited the question. Kindly check.

Comment: @AdeenaLathiya I would try googling those ACPI warnings to see if you find anything related to those warnings and battery.

Comment: Okay let me try that and then get back to you